# Getting prompt during CreateTextFile

Tags: vba, ms-word

CreateTextFile method brings up a msgbox

> "Cannot find the C:\test.txt file. Do you want to create a new file?"

In another project in a different folder this works like it should. Just creates the file but here the message box shows up every time.

> "Cannot find the C:\test.txt file. Do you want to create a new file?"

What could cause that?

```
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFi As TextStream
Dim maFiName As String

'...

maFiName = "test.txt"
        
Set myFi = fs.CreateTextFile(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & maFiName)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is raised by the `CreateTextFile`-command? The exact error msg is shown when you open NotePad with a file name as argument and the file is missing.

Comment: @FunThomas Many thanks for raising my attention. You are right it was a missing path in a shell command that came later in the code. Was to focused on the `CreateTextFile` ... Thanks a lot to everybody for helping me out!